# Is this the best way to complete disable category archive pages?

Tags: templates, page-template, 404-error

I wanted to disable category archive pages because content in my blog will be presented via a number of pages for which I have custom templates like this:

```
add_action('page_template', 'select_page_template');

function select_page_template($template)
{
    $pageName = get_query_var('pagename');

    if ($pageName == "about")
        $page_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/page-templates/about.php';

    return $page_template;
}
```

To do what I wanted, I coded the below so as to redirect all calls from http://www.mydomain.com/[CATEGORY-SLUG] to the 404.php page of the blog:

```
add_action('category_template', 'select_category_template');

function select_category_template($template)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_404 = TRUE;
    return TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
}
```

Does it make sense, especially in respect to SEO? In theory, like this I'm getting the same result I get if I visit a no-page like: http://www.mydomain.com/abcdef

Comment: You could use template_include or replace your themes category.php file with a custom file in a child theme. The filter is actually add_filter('category_template', 'select_category_template');

Comment: But that would not fire a 404 response status code, it will be 200, or I'm wrong?

Comment: You can add the is_404() conditional after any function but is that the best solution?

Comment: I'm not calling is_404(), the code inside function select_category_template($template) is working like a charm, just making sure that it's the cleanest way to achieve what I want. As a matter of fact, my select_category_template function code is working for all category pages.